# Identify which icons PyGTK is using

Tags: pygtk, gtk2

PyGTK 2.24.2 comes with 4000+ icons in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\runtime\share\icons` that take up 26MB. I use py2exe on Windows, which packages these icons, but I probably use only 1% of them, so I would like to remove the extra icons.

**What Python 2.7 code could I use at runtime to trace which icons are actually displayed?** Printing them to the console is fine.

Then I will run my application to generate a list of all used icons, and then I will delete all icons except those actually used.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You're thinking the extra icons are embedded into your binary?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove unneeded icons from the binary distribution for WIndows. One option is trial and error: delete icons that look unneeded until I notice some missing in the application. Another option is using `strace` on Linux and hoping the application uses the same icons on Linux as Windows. (Strace will show me which files the application accesses, and I would use grep to filter it to icons)

Comment: I see what you mean now. I seriously doubt that's recommended practice. I wouldn't do it if I were you. Seeing as I have no experience in Python or py2exe, I can't really answer without looking bad.